# Fill Previous Values - Pentaho Data Integration

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I would like to fill the null values in StoreName with the previous StoreName values. For example the first 7 products are based in the "AKHİSAR" store but the store name is valid for only the first row because of the Excel formatting.

[image]

Here is what i want to achieve:

[image]

I'm not sure if i can do this with Replace in String step.

And i'm using Pentaho 9.0 version.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with the help of [Modified JavaScript Value](https://help.hitachivantara.com/Documentation/Pentaho/Data_Integration_and_Analytics/9.5/Products/Modified_Java_Script_Value) step in Pentaho. Below are the steps:

1. Drag and drop javascript step into your transformation and open the step.
2. Write a script as below:

   ```
   if (StoreName != null){
      var updateStoreName = StoreName;
   }else{
      CONTINUE_TRANSFORMATION
   }
   ```

A [sample gist](https://gist.github.com/rishuatgithub/6a07b54f967f5c274f0c196f4eb3603c) is provided in here for reference.

[image]

If you are using the Javascript in compatibility mode, then you may have to change the variable assigned accordingly. More is available in [the official documentation](https://help.hitachivantara.com/Documentation/Pentaho/Data_Integration_and_Analytics/9.5/Products/Modified_Java_Script_Value).

Comment: Yes I'm using it in compatibility mode, and it worked, thank you so much!

Comment: good solution. If you load the data most steps also have a repeting option, which works just as well. Can use either